# Automate MSRA queryrun in excel

Tags: sql, excel

I have an excel that has to be refreshed every week/month to get the refreshed data from the source system. I am currently trying to automate the process. Is there any way to automate the process? There are many calculations used in the excel file which makes even more difficult for me to achieve it in database level. Any thoughts?

Comment: you can add a basic programming language level abstraction for your autmation you can read your sql data and do calculations within a python script and then via script you can commit your changes to your excel file there is a lot of libraries out there

Comment: Does your Excel have a connection to your database? If it does, what is stopping you just refreshing the data; if not, how is the data getting into Excel?

Comment: The source systems are highly secure for which they allow only certain data to have for our reference. This manual refresh consumes more time.

Comment: Hi  - you haven’t actually provided any detailed information about how the refresh happens. It’s difficult to advise on how to automate a process if you don’t provide any information about the process

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.